# Linking a phone number on Blackberry LabelField

Tags: blackberry, phone-number, labelfield

Is there a way to make text that contains a phone number show up as a clickable link using the Blackberry LabelField?

Example:
"Call me at 1234567" - the 1234567 would be a link that could be used to launch the phone.

This is easy to do on the iPhone UITextView but can't seem to find anything similar for Blackberry...  Or do I need to parse the text manually for phone numbers, URLs, email addresses, etc.?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use [ActiveRichTextField](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/ActiveRichTextField.html)

It will underline the mobile number, URl's , email addresses, etc and on click it will add appropriate menu items like call, open in browser, etc